# How can I add custom toolbar buttons with \enquote command (and possibly any other commands) in TexStudio editor?

Tags: texstudio

I want to add custom toolbar commands in TexStudio editor, specifically: *\enquote*.
I was not able to find this command in toolbar customization. Additionally, if there is an easy solution for this, it will be very useful in the future when I want to add any other commands.
Right now I suspect, there there some commands from packages that are not visible in toolbar customization.
Picture:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a user macro which inserts whatever text you like:

[image]

Once you have defined this, you can add it to a toolbar:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, solved my issue perfectly. 
And also I can add custom icons by right clicking command.
Additionally, maybe someone will find that useful, I have found out that typing %| symbol into custom macros, makes the cursor appear in the right spot, 
example: \enquote{%|}.